# Trouble with Data Migration: Creating and Moving Tables in Excel - Microsoft Power Automate

Tags: excel, power-automate

Flow:

DataFlow:

[image]

What my flow does:

1. I create a table for a excel file that has data but does not have a table. Lets call this excel 1.

2.I then grab all the data from that table I created.

3.I then create a table for a new excel file that I created internally. Lets call this excel2.

4.I then try to input the data that I collected from the table in excel1 into the new table I created in excel2.

5.It only creates the table, but does not move the data into the new excel sheet. So I am doing something wrong with the merging of the data.

Better picture of the last screenshot is attached.

[image]

[image]

The flow I tried is stated in the image.

Comment: What is the error message? And how many rows? There is 100 calls per minute throttle limit.

Comment: Yeah, more I formation required. Does it even enter the last loop? What else can you tell us?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.